# Create a function that updates a variable in any scope

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to reassign a variable **passed into a function**?

(Note: I am not asking if there is any way to reassign a variable, whether in global or parent scope. My goal is to create a function that can set ANY variable in ANY scope to a value.

I understand pass by reference and pass by value - and I'm wondering if there is a way to have functions change the memory reference of a variable in *any* scope (not just a parent scope).

Example:

```js
const setAnyVarTo5 = function(inputVar) {
  // set the inputVar to 5, regardless of its type.
  inputVar = 5; // this is only setting the local variable inputVar. Even if we passed in a reference to an object, we'd still just be changing inputVar's reference, not x's.
}

let x = 7;
setAnyVarTo5(x);
console.log(x); // 7, but desired output is 5

let y = {};
setAnyVarTo5(y);
console.log(y); // {}
```

Comment: `x` is a primitive which is passed as copy, so `inputVar` is not `x` but a local copy variable of the function

Comment: even if `x` is an object, this still won't work since inputVar is only a reference to the location of x's value, not to x itself.

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't have any kind of general references.

Comment: as long as the variable (x) is defined with global scope(`window` in browser), it can be changed anywhere with `window.x = 5`

Comment: @jaysurya The question says *any* scope, so it's not just global scope.

Comment: Yup I didn't say that it works with objects, but with object properties

Comment: @SaymoinSam It doesn't work with properties. `setAnyVarTo5(obj.a)` will not change `obj.a`

Comment: The output of the first example is 7, not 6.

Comment: I didn't mean passing the property, its the same as passing a primitive, I meant passing the object reference, and then change the property

Comment: Primitives can't be passed by reference. There's no underlying object for them. Sure, you can treat them as the equivalent object, but that's syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to the question is "no". It's also not really a great idea to mutate variables like that.

If you can add more context of what you're trying to achieve, I'd be glad to update the answer with a solution.

Comment: In this case there is no specific goal - simply thinking through some JS fundamentals. Realized I couldn't mutate a variable unless I had direct access to it in the scope chain & that I couldn't define some kind of setter / mutator function for use on variables located anywhere.